# failed to resolve com.android.support:support-v7:25.2.0

Tags: android

```
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
```

}

### failed to resolve com.android.support:support-v7:25.2.0

Am trying but cant find the solution please help me

Comment: I want android app some one help me.Am try to make app but i cant done .
I have annual calendar of my college. I want app these give notification of every event on app and display event and also exam time table.some one help me.please

Comment: Do as @lunarwatcher said in his post(answer). If that doesn't work please post your complete `build.gradle` file here.

Comment: As I explained in my answer: Most likely you are trying to get the anroid support repository, but using the wrong import. In the event that is, I added the correct import in my answer. **But** if you aren't trying to get teh support repository, you have to post the entire build.gradle and explain which dependency you are trying to import. Otherwise, no one can help you in a way that isn't guessing

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to get the support repository, this is the correct import:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
```

If your compile api isn't 25, change the version to the latest with your compile api

If it isn't any of these you have to add some context: What is it intent of the import? What do you need it for?

**Side note**

I [believe] the repository you are trying to get is the support repository. The support repository is v4, not v7.